# Should I build a webpage first with one browser and check its compatibility with other browses or the way around?

Tags: cross-browser

When it comes to checking the compatibility of an application against several browsers and their subsequent versions, what the best practices?

Should I finish the page first, using my favorite browser (Chrome), then check the page's compatibility with the rest of the browsers?

Or, should I check the page's compatibility with the other browsers as I go?

What do professionals do?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think it would be best to test all of the browsers at the same time. That way, you can see what works in which browser, and what doesn't, and quickly make the changes as needed. The main place where I look out for issues is Internet Explorer. Its good to have IE specific CSS stylesheets, too.

Comment: So, you mean, IE where I need to concentrate more?

Comment: Yeah, I would say the older IE versions (8, 7, 6) are where you'll have to do a lot more work. IE9 is a bit better, but even then it needs some work. The main thing is that the older IE versions don't have very good standards support.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to check periodically, as you are developing the page. The real issues are firstly CSS, so anytime you are modifying CSS, it would be wise to check it. Secondly is JavaScript. jQuery makes javascript compatibility much much easier. So you should use that...

The problem with waiting to finish the page, is that if you need to do rework, it is much more expensive by the time the page is finished.

This is the case in software in general; the sooner a bug/problem is found, the cheaper it is to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very project dependent. If you know the exact specs of your page with no chance of major modifications, then check IE often (all other browser fixes are usually minor)

If you`re unsure about the final outcome of the project, then it`s a waste of time fixing every inconsistency that IE has if you`re planning to make revisions. In general however, it is wise to check browser compatibility at any large point in a project, such as installing an applet, embedding a video, flash or iframe.